# Proof of existence of a point in a closed set $C$ closest to a point not in $C$

Tags: real-analysis

Note: The question was previously asked in [Prove that there exists a nearest point in a closed set $A \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ to a point outside of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75343/prove-that-there-exists-a-nearest-point-in-a-closed-set-a-subset-mathbfrn) answered with a wonderful simple proof.

This question is to clarify a similar but alternate proof of the same theorem in "The Mathematics of Nonlinear Programming" by Peressini, Sullivan, and Uhl.

**Theorem**: If $C$ is a closed (convex or not) subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ does not belong to $C$, then there is a vector $x^* \in C$ that is closest to $y$, that is, $\forall x \in C$:
$$\left\Vert y - x^* \right\Vert \leq \left\Vert y - x\right\Vert$$ 
The first half of the proof is stated:

Let $\alpha$ be the largest number such that $\forall x \in C, \ \alpha \leq \left\Vert y -x \right\Vert$. Then there is a sequence $\{x^{(k)}\}$ of elements of $C$ such that:
$$\alpha = \lim_k \left\Vert y - x^{(k)} \right\Vert$$

Comment: $\alpha$ is just the infinium of the distance of $C$ and $y$

**Question**: How did we get to the existence of sequence $\{x^{(k)}\}$?

I understand $C$ is a closed set such that limit of a sequence in $C$ is also in $C$, but I don't think that's relevant to the distance function. I knew before that the distance function or $\left\Vert y - x \right\Vert$ for fixed $y$ is a continuous function, and I think that's the key, but the book has omitted this property, as in it's not mentioned anywhere and this book is more for undergraduates with little experience in Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with $C$ being closed or any property of this set, this has just to do with the defining property of the infimum of a set which permit to deduce the following property.

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a subset of the real line and $\alpha:=\inf\,A$ its infimum, then there is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of elements of $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\,a_n=\alpha$.

In order to prove this result, just note that as $\alpha$ is the infimum of $A$, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is some $a_n\in \left[\alpha,\alpha+\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Otherwise, $\alpha$ would not be the infimum as $\alpha+\frac{1}{2n}$ would be a lower bound for $A$. Then this $\{a_n\}$ is the sequence living in $A$ and converging to $\alpha$.

Once this is clear, the existence result for your sequence is just applying the above proposition to the set $\{||y-x||\,|\,x\in C\}$.